# Bad practice to use 5 different method parameters?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have two buttons that each can perform two different implementations (whether selected or not), so that's 4 possible implementations in total.  After coding it all out, I noticed I had  20+ lines of code for each implementation and only 1 or 2 variables were different in each. I decided I want to clean this up and have each implementation call separate, smaller methods and pass the inconsistent variables as parameters.

I figure this is a better practice b/c I'm reusing code. However, in one of my methods I have to pass 5 different arguments implement the method with correct conditions.

Is having this many parameters in a method a bad practice?

Answer (score 3):

Having many parameters is not necessary a bad thing.

There are patterns that create a class to group all the parameters into one object that may seem cleaner to you. Another alternative is to use a dictionary for with all the parameters as the single configuration parameter. Some of Apples classes does this (for example [title font configuration in the navigation bar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/titleTextAttributes)).

I *personally* would say that code repetition is worse than many methods calling each other and having multiple parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If it allow you to remove many duplicate lines, I don't see any problem to do it this way.
If it's to remove 1 or 2 lines then it might not worth the effort.

In fact you can pass as many arguments as needed. There might be other ways to do what you what to achieve but without the code your 5 arguments seems valid at first glance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no specific number of parameters that is generally "bad practice". A method should have as many parameters as it needs. That said, there are cases where having a large number of parameters may indicate that a better design might be possible. For example, there are cases where you may realize an object should be tracking some value in a member variable instead of having the value passed into its methods every time.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's okay to use 5 params because some objective-c default method are also having 4 params like

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateConvMenu:)
                                 notificationName:@"NSConvertersChanged" 
                                           object:converterArray];
```

What we can do to make it more clear is giving a better format to your code

Comment: Or how about `transitionFromView: toView: duration: options: completion:` on UIView... 5 arguments right there :D

Comment: actually I always use notificationcenter so I remember this example haha :D

Answer (score 2):

disclaimer: I know zilch about objective c

It is difficult to say without seeing the code in question, and it completely depends on what you are doing.  To say that having a method with five parameters is bad practice right off the bat is a bit presumptive, although it is certainly good practice to keep the number of method parameters as small as possible.

The fact that this method sounds like an internal 'helper' method (and not a publicly exposed component of an API) gives you more lee-way then you might otherwise have, but typically you do not want to be in a situation where a method is doing different things based on some arcane combination of parameters.

When I run into methods with uncomfortably long signatures that cannot be restructured without creating redundant code, I typically do one of the following:

- wrap the offensive method with several more concise methods.  You might create, as an example, a method for each of your 'implementations', with a good name indicating its purpose that accepts only the arguments needed for that purpose.  It would then delegate to the internal, smellier method. The smelly method would only ever be used in your 'implementation specific' wrappers instead of being scattered throughout your code.  Using the well named wrappers in its stead, developers will understand your intent without having to decipher the meaning of the parameters.
- Create a Class that encapsulates the data needed by the method.  If what the method does depends on the state of some system or subsystem, then encapsulate that state!  I do this often with 'XXContext' type classes. Now your method can inspect and analyze this contextual data and take the appropriate actions.  This is good for refactoring as well.  If the method in the future needs more information to accomplish its tasks or implement new functionality, you can add this data to the argument object, instead of having to change every bit of code that uses the method.  Only code that needs to make use of the changes will have to supply the the appropriate values to the contextual data.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those subjective questions that's really hard to answer definitively.

I don't mind a number of parameters in an Objective C method as it can make the API that's being called more clear (and the parameters can be nice & type safe, too).

If you can distill those many functions down to a smaller number of functions (or a "base" function which is called from all the other functions), that's probably also makes for cleaner code that's easier to follow and read.  Plus if you make an update to that "base" function, the functionality change will be picked up by all the ways you call your action (that's can also be a good or bad thing, of course).